# Under Android NDK, can a native window be created without Java calls to retrieve the surface?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to develop an android app fully in native code using C++. The Android NDK api's are using a Java object. For example I saw the method:

```
int32_t ANativeWindow_getHeight(ANativeWindow* window);
```

But to create an `ANativeWindow` I need a Java Surface Object.

```
ANativeWindow* ANativeWindow_fromSurface(JNIEnv* env, jobject surface);
```

Is there any other way to get the details without using any java objects?

I do not want to use a Java callback.

Comment: No. Even if your java app is an empty surfaceview, you still have to invoke it and pass it down...

Comment: Thank You... I guess I need to stick to call back in the worst case :(

Comment: Even if you don't write any Java code yourself, a Native Activity will still of necessity run a lot of Android-provided classes compiled from Java source within your application process, as that's just how major parts of the system work internally.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible... After a long time  I have realized it. The answer will be to use some third party libraries which will in turn provide the the api's via java call back. So call back is the only solution available.